# Why IOCP doesn't work in BeginExecuteReader

Tags: c#, asynchronous, iocp

I've read many articles say that IOCP is used in BeginXX/EndXX pair calls.
However, when i test them, my result shown that IOCP didn't work in BeginExecuteReader call, while it worked just fine in BeginGetResponse call.

I'm very confused with this outcome. Can anyone tell me the reason? Is there anything wrong with my test code?

Here's the test below:

1. test with BeginGetResponse

   Code:

   ```
   public static void IoThread2()
   {
     ThreadPool.SetMinThreads(5, 3);
     ThreadPool.SetMaxThreads(5, 3);
     int w; int io;
     ThreadPool.GetAvailableThreads(out w, out io);
     int cid = Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId;
     Console.WriteLine("Begin:" + w.ToString() + ";" + io.ToString() + "; id = " + cid.ToString());
     ManualResetEvent waitHandle = new ManualResetEvent(false);
     WebRequest request = HttpWebRequest.Create("http://www.cnblogs.com/");
     AsyncCallback cb = new AsyncCallback(IOThread2CallBack);
     request.BeginGetResponse(cb, request);
     waitHandle.WaitOne();
   }

   public static void IOThread2CallBack(IAsyncResult ar)
   {
    try
    {
        WebRequest request = (WebRequest)ar.AsyncState;
        int w2; int io2;
        ThreadPool.GetAvailableThreads(out w2, out io2);
        int cid2 = Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId;
        Console.WriteLine("End:" + w2.ToString() + ";" + io2.ToString() + "; id = " + cid2.ToString());
        var response = request.EndGetResponse(ar);
     }catch (Exception ex){ }
   }
   ```

   Result:

   ```
   Begin:5;3; id = 10
   End:5;2; id = 13
   ```

   One IO thread was used to execute the callback.
2. test with BeginExecuteReader
   Code:

   ```
   public static void IoThread1()
   {
        ThreadPool.SetMinThreads(5, 3);
        ThreadPool.SetMaxThreads(5, 3);
        int w; int io;
        ThreadPool.GetAvailableThreads(out w, out io);
        int cid = Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId;
        Console.WriteLine("Begin:" + w.ToString() + ";" + io.ToString() + "; id = " + 
                       cid.ToString());
        SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
        connection.Open();
        AsyncCallback da = new AsyncCallback(IoThreadCallBack);
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(s_QueryDatabaseListScript, connection);
        IAsyncResult ir = command.BeginExecuteReader(da,                             
                             command,System.Data.CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);
        ManualResetEvent waitHandle = new ManualResetEvent(false);
        waitHandle.WaitOne();
   }

   public static void IoThreadCallBack(IAsyncResult ar)
   {
    int w; int io;
    ThreadPool.GetAvailableThreads(out w, out io);
    int cid = Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId;
    Console.WriteLine("End:" + w.ToString() + ";" + io.ToString() + "; id = " +  
                      cid.ToString());
    SqlCommand command = (SqlCommand)ar.AsyncState;
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    try
    {
          using (SqlDataReader reader = command.EndExecuteReader(ar))
          {
               while (reader.Read())
               {
                   sb.Append(reader.GetString(0)).Append("; ");
               }
          }
     }
     catch (Exception ex){ }
     finally
     {
          command.Connection.Close();  
     }
    }
   ```

   Result:

   ```
   Begin:5;3; id = 10
   End:4;3; id = 7
   ```

   Another work thread was used to execute the callback

What's the problem?

Comment: I'm confused... We *expect* the callback to be executed on a different thread. That is largely **the entire point** of using Begin*...? Note: using a Begin/End callback to just open a wait-handle is pointless - if you're going to wait at the caller, you might as well not use Begin* at all.

Comment: @MarcGravell, I think the question is why was a worker thread used in the second case and not an IOCP.

Comment: I/O completion ports are available on simple I/O requests, started by an overlapped Read/WriteFile() call.  There is nothing simple about a SQL I/O request, a big hunking chunk of software sits in between called the "SQL Native Client".  As well as a chunk of C++/CLI code in System.Data.SqlClient.  TDS is the protocol, SNI is the interface, the channel can be named pipes, sockets or shared memory.  All rather poorly documented and invisible to disassembling eyes.

Answer (score 0):

Your repro is very creative. This is an interesting case.

Try starting 100 SqlCommands with the command text "WAITFOR DELAY '02:00';" and observe how the thread counts develop over time (start a timer which prints the statistics).

My guess is that we will see that far less than 100 threads are consumed (meaning this part of the async behavior is working). For some reason SqlCommand is using the "wrong" thread-pool threads but this might not reduce scalability at all.

Comment: What we have observed only means that your callback executed on a worker thread. But the IO might still have executed as IOCP. And thats what is important, because it lets you have thousands of outstanding operations without having thousands of thread. Please try this experiment.